# how to speed up tar, just build a package without compression

Tags: tar, file-management

I have a large folder, 2TB, with 1000000 files on a Linux machine. I want to build a package with tar. I do not care about the size of the tar file, so I do not need to compress the data. How can I speed `tar` up? It takes me an hour to build a package with `tar -cf xxx.tar  xxx/`. I have a powerful CPU with 28 cores, and 500GB memory，is there a way to make `tar` run multithreaded?

Or, alternatively, is there any good way to transfer a large number of small files between different folders and between different servers? My filesystem is ext4.

Comment: Tar does not compress.

Comment: What will you do with the tar file when you have it. This may affect the answer, as a speed up in one area may slow down another, or vica versa.

Comment: The CPU and the number of cores don't make much difference as the operation of creating a `tar` archive is disk-bound, not CPU-bound. You could use several `tar` processes running in parallel, each handling their own subset of the files, creating separate archives, but they would still need to fetch all the data from the single disk.

Comment: @ ctrl-alt-delor after the tar file , i will transfer that with network or just mv to another folder.

Comment: @ Kusalananda  thanks for your suggest. do you have any idea about how to automatically deploy tar tasks and automatically split folders

Comment: @GuoYong the ideal split would be a combination of number of files and aggregate disk usage. If you're looking to copy the files elsewhere to another server why not just use `scp` and skip the `tar` phase entirely?

Comment: reiserfs usually deals  better with a lot of smaller files in a directory (though not being developed, it is already starting to show some bugs). You might prefer to make a loop image and mount that over the directory, to evade the need for messy changes of your installation.

Comment: @Kusalananda in theory, TAR is disk bound, but GNU tar has been implemented in an inefficient way, so you cannot reach the expected disk speed. I recommend to try `star` that uses only approx. 1/3 of the CPU time GNU tar needs for the same task.

Answer (score 14):

As @Kusalananda says in the comments, tar is disk-bound.  One of the best things you can do is put the output on a separate disk so the writing doesn't  slow down the reading.

If your next step is to move the file across the network, I'd suggest that you create the tar file over the network in the first place:

```
$ tar -cf - xxx/ | ssh otherhost 'cat > xxx.tar'
```

This way the local host only has to read the files, and doesn't have to also accommodate the write bandwidth consumed by tar.  The disk output from tar is absorbed by the network connection and the disk system on `otherhost`.

Comment: Better yet, you might just untar at the other end, and save half the writes there. OP seems to just want to transfer some files.

Comment: @muru thanks for the suggestion. i want to 1. tar the file in serverA  2. nc the tar file to serverB  3. untar the tar file in serverB. Do you have any way to improve this process?

Comment: @Jim L. thanks for your help. i want to 1. tar the file in serverA 2. nc the tar file to serverB 3. untar the tar file in serverB. Do you have any way to improve this process?

Comment: @GuoYong Sounds like you want `rsync`, not `tar`.

Comment: Is this approach appropriate and reliable to do over an automatic backup cron between different hosts? @Jim L.

Answer (score 7):

> Or, alternatively, is there any good way to transfer a large number of small files between different folders and between different servers? My filesystem is ext4.

Rsync over ssh is something I use on a regular basis. It preserves file permissions, symlinks, etc., when used with the `--archive` option:

```
rsync -av /mnt/data <server>:/mnt
```

This example copies the local directory `/mnt/data` and its contents to a remote server inside `/mnt`. It invokes ssh to set up the connection. No rsync daemon is needed on either side of the wire.

This operation can also be performed between 2 local directories, or from remote to local.